# Laravel 8 http testing error Failed asserting that two strings are equal

Tags: php, testing, laravel-8

I want to test the endpoint Sign Up (you can consider signup as registration), and at the same time I want to return the response object and redirect the user to sign in endpoint, but when I run the test it gives this error.

```
  • Tests\Unit\ProjectTest > http
  Failed asserting that two strings are equal.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\tests\Unit\ProjectTest.php:49
     45▕             'Select'=>'Software Engneering',
     46▕             'username'=>'username',
     47▕             'email'=>'email@email'
     48▕         ]);
  ➜  49▕         $response->assertRedirect('/signin');
     50▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:92
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
  --- Expected
  +++ Actual
  @@ @@
  -'http://localhost/signin'
  +'http://localhost'

  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   0.19s
```

And this is the code for the test

```
public function test_http(){
        $response = $this->post('/SignUp',[
            'id'=>'4',
            'first_name'=>'name',
            'middle_name'=>'name',
            'family_name'=>'name',
            'password'=>'password',
            'gender'=>'male',
            'work'=>'work',
            'Select'=>'Software Engneering',
            'username'=>'username',
            'email'=>'email@email'
        ]);
        $response->assertRedirect('/signin');
    }
```

I looked for a solution but none of them helped me.

Comment: The error is pretty clear right?  The test expects to finish up at `/signin`, but in fact you finish up at `/`. So you need to look at your controller and work out why that is happening.  PS - are your routes really using inconsistent capitalisation (`SignUp` vs `signin`), or is that a bug?

Comment: @Don'tPanic , Which controller sign in or signup, and how I can spot the error? No, It is not a bug I use inconsistent capitalization.

Comment: AFAIK Laravel 8's registration and login do not use `/SignUp` or `/signin`, so you must have your own registration/auth code? So ... where did you do it? :-) Check your routes: `php artisan route:list` - which controller/method handles a POST to `/SignUp`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic , Okay I found it, what I should to do next ? If you want, I can edit my question and add the code that handle POST Sign Up

Answer (score -1):

i had a simular case where my routes was the issue, all you can do is run
**php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear**

I changed my routes without without clearing it, I hope this helps someone in the future